# Remove space between characters

Tags: math-mode, spacing, kerning

How can I remove the space between this

```
\newcommand{\deref}{\ensuremath{\rightarrowtriangle}\xspace}

$b\deref\mathbf{r}_S$
```

such that the arrow is as closest to the two surounding characters as possible?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Put one extra pair of braces around the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,xspace}
\newcommand{\deref}{\ensuremath{{\rightarrowtriangle}}\xspace}


\begin{document}
  $b\deref\mathbf{r}_S$
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, what is the intention of using `ensuremath` and `\xspace` here? It is better not to use them.

Comment: cool, thanks! what does the two braces do?

Comment: @Gabriel The extra pair of braces converts the relational nature of arrow (`\mathrel` so adding space) in to ordinary symbol (`\mathord`) which doesn't have spaces around.

Comment: As usual: `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` are redundant and should disappear.

Comment: @egreg: I forgot `\ensuremath` :). Added a note now.